# Unable to clone ssh-based GIT URIs in a Windows Container

Tags: windows, ssh, docker, git

Not sure what happened, but up until last week, I've been able to clone git repositories via SSH-based URIs in my Windows containers based on the `dotnet-framework-docker` container.  Now, suddenly without warning, when I go to clone - even a public repository, I get this error:

```
C:\>git clone git@github.com:atrauzzi/praxis.git
git clone git@github.com:atrauzzi/praxis.git
Cloning into 'praxis'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here's a simple `Dockerfile` that can be used to reproduce the issue:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework
SHELL ["powershell"]

# Install Git
RUN New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path 'c:/git';
RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.1.windows.1/Git-2.15.1-64-bit.exe" -OutFile "/git-installer.exe" -UseBasicParsing;
RUN Start-Process -FilePath C:/git-installer.exe -ArgumentList '/VERYSILENT', '/NORESTART', '/NOCANCEL', '/SP-', '/DIR="c:/git"' -PassThru | Wait-Process;
RUN rm /git-installer.exe;
```

I'm not sure at this point what could be causing this.  The only suspicious thing is that if I try to run the mingw based `ssh.exe`, it prints a blank line and then exits.

Some suspicions I have are obviously around mingw and the fact that I'm running things in a container.

cc https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/issues/61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess - but I suspect that the dotnet framework image used to have the SSH key for GitHub already...  That said looking into https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1403 as the root/ideal fix.